# Session Values Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am developing a web application. In that I am passing session values like:

```
Session["userid"] = txtuser.ToString();
Session["name"] = txtname.ToString();
```

Now i am getting session values finely. I am doing some manipulations with these `userid`. Lets assume 3 users come to my website like `user1@domain.com`, `user2@domain.com`, `user3@domain.com` and hit the login button all 3 users at a time. In that case `user3@domain.com` getting user1@domain.com details means that in userid session it is passing user1@domain.com value instead of user3@domain.com.

I tried the following options:

- Checked the session ids of users which are different for each user.
- In `signout` page, I used `session.Abandon()`
- Placed some sleep function when i reading user input , That as well not worked.

Can anyone suggest me what is wrong?

Comment: I guess you have static fields. That would explain that those users share the same values. Don't do that. The session itself is not shared.

Comment: Can you explain me in better if you don't mine?

Comment: You should show more code, the code posted doesn't explain why different users overwrite each others session. Do you have static variables?

Comment: Show the definitions of `txtuser` and `txtname` and how you assign values into it

Comment: Yeah sounds like you've got some statics variables/methods occurring.  Sessions are unique to the computer/browser so unless you're trying to log in 3 users from the same browser then you're dealing with an issue within your code.

Comment: Hi all , Thank you very much . i removed static variables and it worked for me now....Its eaten my brian from yesterday...